# GridView: If the selected value of dropdownlist is yes,first value of dropdown = yes , and 2 columns will appear the rest cells=false;

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

- I have a simple gridview.

  - I have made a column textbox to dropdownlist with 2 values : yes/no .
  - I have on event dropdownlist if the value == yes then two columns
    will appear.
  - But How can I make that the rest of cells to be false I mean the user
    can't write into them until the value from the dropdown is Yes.
  - If the users is choosing No in the dropdown , the code for no is executing but the value in the dropdown will be always the first .

  example:
  Yes
  No

If I choose No , everything is fine but I want dropdown to get the value in the first place of what I choosed

Comment: I've tried if the selected value == Yes { dropdownlist1.value == Yes; } something like that . but I can't make it work..and I know how to make a column invisible but the problem is the dropdow ..read what I said please

Comment: ok here's the problem : the gridview has 2 values : Yes/No ! , I can only choose Yes because is the second value .

Answer (score 1):

You can either make a column invissible like this

this.dataGridView.Columns["columnName"].
Visible = false;

or set it as readonly:

this.dataGridView.Columns["columnName].ReadOnly = true;

If that is what you mean.